# VSTS Template: Container (PREVIEW) proper steps?

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm trying Container (PREVIEW) in Visual Studio Team Services. I really have no idea about containers just curious. So far I was able to run Ubuntu and install Docker, also created account in Docker Hub, and then able to established Docker Registry Connection. Now I queue the build and get this error.

```
Unhandled: No Docker file matching /home/christianlouislivioco/myagent/_work/1/s/**/Dockerfile was found.
```

How to resolve this?

Also these questions: 
What procedures did I miss? What to do next? Any tips regarding this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create a dockerfile for your application? If you "*have no idea about containers*", a good starting point is the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Docker (Build an image) task:

If you check Use Default Build Context option, then it uses source directory (e.g. `[agent working directory]\1\s`) as the build context, so the Dockerfile need to be existing in the source directory (can be in child folder). (Map server files to build agent in **Get sources** section, you also can copy Dockerfile to source directory)

If you uncheck Use Default Build Context, you can specify the Build context path that contains Dockerfile.

[image]

Based on your description, you are using default build context with Container (Preview) template, so check the Source setting in **Get sources** section.

After pushing image to server (E.g. Docker Hub, Azure Container Registry), you can run this image or do other things. [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)